# Update EF6 Migration Class Target hash after manual edit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Is there any way to manually generate the hash used in an EF6 migration target?

I have edited an auto-generated migration class to include a schema that gets provided at runtime, as I could not find any other way to make migrations work with this kind of setup. Now the migration works fine and creates the proper tables, including a custom __MigrationHistory using HistoryContext, but Database.Initialize throws the exception below.

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to update database to match the current
>   model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is
>   disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based
>   migration or enable automatic migration. Set
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
>   automatic migration.

I can not enable Automatic Migrations as I am doing them manually.

As of now I am assuming that the hashed context contained in the Target variable in the migration resx file does not match up with the migration, due to the changed schema, and I am looking for a way to update it.

Comment: when you say you are including a schema that gets provided at runtime, that sounds a bit odd.  can you expand upon that a bit more, perhaps provide some code to illustrate what you mean?

Comment: @Claies I have multiple instances of the same tables living in a database, each owned by a website. Each website sends in a unique name to a datastore class, which passes that to the DbContext through a custom constructor, which then sets HasDefaultSchema during OnModelCreating. In addition to that I have a static class that holds the schema name that the default constructor can get in case it ever gets called.

Comment: I'm not sure that that sort of modelling can actually be done correctly in Entity Framework.

Comment: I don't think I understand: is the schema static, or are you creating new tables at runtime?